# Protect Excel file from being shared to another computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an Excel VBA Code which I am planning to sell.
Now, I want to put certain protection, so that when someone pays and downloads the utility, he should be able to use it only on that one PC. He should not be able to share that utility.
Is there any possible way I can do that?

Comment: Nothing will protect it 100% - Excel is not fully secure, despite having some degree of security.

Comment: If you need it to be secure, then you would have to convert it to a .NET application (VB.NET is very similar) and then sell that compiled application instead of just selling a workbook that has macros in it.

Comment: And even then... there's nothing stopping them from installing it on more than one computer unless you include some very heavy duty security.

Comment: MAC or Windows only?

Comment: @braX: VB.NET is not very similar, but it **is** a .NET application. This will nog add security, because of the existence of decompilers.

Comment: In my opinion, it is VERY similar. I convert things from VBA to VB.NET all the time and it's not that complex. But as previously stated, even then, nothing is 100% secure if someone is stubborn enough.

Comment: Windows.. I am not a technical person, so I don't know much about this. So, if any solution to this is possible, please let me know... Thanks

Comment: On first run get the mac address of the pc, next run the code checks that the mac address is the same, if not then it stops (or waits 30 mins and then posts an error message).